# How to get From and To number from Recording status callback

Tags: php, laravel, twilio

Hi i'm currently integrating my laravel project with Twilio. How can I get the From and To numbers from recording status callback?

Im currently doing an automated interview using twilio where only the responses of the user are being recorded I want to get the recordings together with the from and to numbers.

This is my first time using twilio. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

One way is to pass URL Query Parameters as part of the Recording Status callback to your application.

The general concept is explained here, [How to Share Information Between Your Applications](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/how-share-information-between-your-applications).